# Elastic Ingest Pipeline split field and create a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-pipeline

Dear freindly helpers,

I have an index that is fed by a database via Kafka. Now this database holds a field that aggregates a couple of pieces of information like so key/value; key/value; (don't ask for the reason, I have no idea who designed it liked that and why ;-) )

93/4; 34/12;

it can be empty, or it can hold 1..n key/value pairs.

I want to use an ingest pipeline and ideally have a "nested" field which holds all values that are in tha field.

Probably like this:

{"categories":
{ "93": 7,
"82": 4
}
}

The use case is the following: we want to visualize the sum of a filtered number of these categories (they tell me how many minutes a specific process took longer) and relate them in ranges.

Example: I filter categories x, y ,z and then group how many documents for the day had no delay, which had a delay up to 5 minutes and which had a delay between 5 and 15 minutes.

I have tried to get the fields neatly separated with the kv processor and wanted to work from there on but it was a complete wrong approach I guess.

```
"kv": {
      "field": "IncomingField",
      "field_split": ";",
      "value_split": "/",
      "target_field": "delays",
      "ignore_missing": true,
      "trim_key": "\\s",
      "trim_value": "\\s",
      "ignore_failure": true
    }
```

When I test the pipeline it seems ok

```
"delays": {
            "62": "3",
            "86": "2"
          }
```

but there are two things that don't work.

1. I can't know upfront how many of these combinations I have and thus converting the values from string t int in the same pipeline is an issue.
2. When I want to create a kibana index pattern I end up with many fields like delay.82 and delay.82.keyword which does not make sense at all for the usecase as I can't filter (get only the sum of delays where the key is one of x,y,z) and aggregate.

I have looked into other processors (dorexpander) but can't really get my head around how to get this working.

I hope my question is clear (I lack english skills, sorry) and that someone can point me at the right direction.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather structure them as an array of objects with shared accessors, for instance:

```json
[ {key: 93, value: 7}, ...]
```

That way, you'll be able to aggregate on `categories.key` and `categories.value`.

So this means iterating the categories' `entrySet()` using a custom script processor like so:

```json
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": "extracts k/v pairs",
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            def categories = ctx.categories;
            def kv_pairs = new ArrayList();
    
            for (def pair : categories.entrySet()) {
              def k = pair.getKey();
              def v = pair.getValue();
              kv_pairs.add(["key": k, "value": v]);
            }
            
            ctx.categories = kv_pairs;
          """
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "categories": {
          "82": 4,
          "93": 7
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

P.S.: Do make sure your `categories` field is [mapped as `nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) b/c otherwise you'll lose the connections between the keys & the values (also called flattening).

Comment: Hi, sorry I misread the question. My starting point was `{"delays":{"62":"3","86":"2"}}` and that's where `entrySet()` would work. Since the actual starting point is a string like `93/4; 34/12;`, you'll need to split it first by the spaces and then by `/` -- all of which can be done inside of the script. Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Joe, thanks for the reply and sorry for the late answer. That solves half of my issue I guess. In the source that I have the field looks like stated in the first part of my post: "65/3; 81/1; 98/5"

SO woould you first apply the kv processor and then your proposed solution?

Comment: Yes -- either that or all of the KV splitting in one single script.

Comment: Would you be willing to help out more with the scripting. These ar emy first steps in scripting painless and I have to say that finding the right documentation is really painful! Where to find all methods,etc etc. What would be the function equivalent to the kv processor if I wanted to use it. Or do you have a good source of documentation probably where I can read on? I seem to wander in circles between elastic, java site and others. Sorry for my lack of knowledge here and kudos for your willingsness to help!

Comment: I ended up using two processors in a row in the ingest node as per Joes recommendation. Thus for me the answer solved my problem! Thanks Joe!

Comment: No prob. I’m no java pro so I’d have done the same as you — google